# reactjs using redux and thunks dispatch doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to use redux and react hooks
to consume an api but I have problem because it is not calling my action

> return dispatch

for some reason he doesn't get in my dispatch
I don't know where I can go wrong or how I can fix it

my action:

```
const FetchSucess = data  => ({
    type:FETCH_SUCESS,
    data
});
const FetchFailed = error  => ({
    type:FETCH_FAIL,
    error
});
const isLoadingFetch = () => ({type: FETCH_LOADING})

export const getAllProducts = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
        api.get('/products')
        .then( response => { console.log(response);})
        .catch( err => { dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));});
    }
}
```

my reducer:

```
import {FETCH_FAIL, FETCH_SUCESS, FETCH_LOADING} from '../../actions/fetch/actionType';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: [],
    fn:[],
    mw:[],
    ft:[],
    ww:[],
    bs:[],
    stattrek:[],
    normal:[],
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          filteredProducts: action.data.listProducts,
          products: action.data.listProducts,
          fn: action.data.fn,
          mw: action.data.mw,
          ft: action.data.ft,
          ww: action.data.ww,
          bs: action.data.bs,
          stattrek: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 1),
          normal: action.data.listProducts.filter(value=> value.id_types === 2)
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

my app:

```
import styles from "../assets/cardStyle";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllProducts } from '../store/actions/fetch/index'
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Cards() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const dispatch = useDispatch(getAllProducts());
    const products = useSelector(state => {
    })

    products.map(product=>(
        <div>
        <Container fixed>
            <Grid container direction="row" >
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Card className={classes.card}>
                        <CardContent className= {classes.cardCarousel}>
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook together with your
                                guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the mussels, if you like.
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </Card>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    </div> 
    ))

    return (
        {products}
    );
}
```

I've already tested and apparently my redux is working it returns me to normal state
it arrives at me action but doesn't call my function calling my api:

```
return dispatch => {
    dispatch (isLoadingFetch ());
    api.get ('/ products')
    .then (response => {console.log (response);})
    .catch (err => {dispatch (FetchFailed (err.message));});
}
```

my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

and my reducer combiners

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import fetchReducer from '../reducers/fetch/index'
export default combineReducers({
    data: fetchReducer
});
```

Comment: You need to dispath  FetchSucess   here ` .then( response => { console.log(response);})`

Comment: @SuleymanSah It's not because of that
it is just my return dispatch I use console.log just for testing ..

he doesn't even enter my .then or axios.get

Comment: Can you add all related codes to the question?  Also do you mean it does not console log anything here ?   .then( response => { console.log(response);})

Comment: Yes it does my action but it does not return
I think this is all related to the question

Comment: Did you apply thunk middleware? Can you add the store code to the question?

Comment: yes i aplly i post my combiners and my store now i edit

Comment: Why don't you select anything here in your component?   const products = useSelector(state => {
    })

Comment: Something like this must be done there: const products = useSelector(state => state.data)

Comment: I just gave console.log because my return was null,
for some reason he doesn't come into my action

Comment: Can you try like this in your component? const products = useSelector(state => state.data.products)

Comment: I had done this the problem is not in reducer but in my action method

he doesn't return my dispatch

he doesn't call any of mine

dispatch (fetchsucess ()

dispatch (isloading ())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203801/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-felipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are using useDispatch wrong.

It must be used like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
  const loadProducts = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProducts();
  }, [loadProducts]);
```

Secondly, you need to extract products from useSelector like this:

```
  const products = useSelector(state => state.data.products)
```

Then you need to dispath fetchSuccess here

```
export const getAllProducts = () => {
  console.log("here is get all products");
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(isLoadingFetch());
    api
      .get("/products")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response data", response.data);
        dispatch(FetchSucess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(FetchFailed(err.message));
      });
  };
};
```

So all component code can be like this to show your products:
(note that I simplifed the render to show only product name)

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { getAllProducts } from "../store/actions/fetch/index";

export default function Cards() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadProducts = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProducts();
  }, [loadProducts]);

  const products = useSelector(state => state.data.products); // OR  state.data.filteredProducts

  console.log("products:", products);

  if (products && products.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        {products.map(product => (
          <li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div>No products</div>;
  }
}
```